# What is the purpose/use of 'name' propery in export default{}

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, vue.js

I am learning vuejs and I can't understand why this name is needed.

```
<template>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'NotFound'
  }
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

For example, you can see the source of the above code in this file https://github.com/misterGF/CoPilot/blob/master/src/components/404.vue
the name does nothing but why do we need it.

Comment: looks like it is specific to that component framework (CoPilot?) so that it shows up as "Not found" when something returns with a 404.

Comment: Is `name` required though inside `export default{}`, that is what I wanted to know. Also, CoPilot is not using the value inside the template, so I thought it might be required.

Comment: One main benefit is to make debugging easy.... if there is a emerging wrong in your component, vue devtools will use this name to point oit the component , otherwise it will use `<AnonymousComponent>` which is not very exact

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Components can recursively invoke themselves in their own template. However, they can only do so with the name option

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Recursive-Components